# Нахождение косинуса

Tags: c#, математика

Надо найти значение косинуса, исходя из градусов которые ввел юзер
Но когда я ввожу 90 градусов, код мне выдает не табличное значение "0", а совсем непонятное число 
(Заранее прошу прощения за говнокод, постарался показать что я вообще хочу получить в каждой строчке)

```
        string i = textBox9.Text; // беру цифру (градусы) которую ввел пользователь
        double cos1 = double.Parse(i); // преобразую 
        double cos2 = cos1 * Math.PI / 180; // преобразую градусы в радианы так как Math.Cos воспринимает только радианы
        double cos3 = Math.Cos(cos2); // нахожу косинус в радианах
        double cos4 = cos3 * 180 / Math.PI; // перевожу радианы в градусы обратно
        textBox8.Text = cos4.ToString(); // вывожу
```

Comment: А что, синусы-косинусы тоже угловые величины и их тоже надо переводить из радиан в градусы? Вот это крутая новость...

Answer (score 1):

```
        string i = "90";
        double cos1 = double.Parse(i); // преобразую
        double cos2 = cos1 * Math.PI / 180; // преобразую градусы в радианы так как Math.Cos воспринимает только радианы
        double cos3 = Math.Cos(cos2); // нахожу косинус в радианах
        double cos4 = cos3 * 180 / Math.PI; // перевожу радианы в градусы обратно
        Console.Write(cos3);
```

По сути ваш код. [Выдает](https://ideone.com/t7d3Hs), как видите, что-то там на 10 в минус семнадцатой степени. Практически ноль, что и требовалось (погрешность вычислений, самого "пи" наконец).

И не надо переводить значение косинуса "в градусы из радианов", смешно же...

Comment: "Вывести синус, косинус и тангенс числа, заданного в градусах" - вот задание которое мне надо выполнить. Поэтому и пытаюсь из радианов в градусы перевести =)

Comment: Так, последняя попытка... Вы вообще-то понимаете, что косинус и синус не могут быть больше 1? А чему *по-вашему* равен синус 90 градусов? Косинус нуля градусов? Посчитайте...

Comment: А, понял, простите за шлупость)

Comment: Зачем в коде оставлена строка `double cos4 = cos3 * 180 / Math.PI;`.  Это шутка?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Чтобы ее прокомментировать. Как видите, я вывел `cos3`.